TomTom marker don't show up on map
I want to add marker on my geoposition. That's what i did:
mapFragment.getMapAsync { tomtomMap: TomTomMap ->
            val loc:GeoPoint = tomtommap.currentLocation!!.position
            val markerOptions =
                MarkerOptions(
                    coordinate = loc,
                    tag = "Tag",
                    pinImage = ImageFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.children),
                    pinIconImage = ImageFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.children),
                )
            tomtomMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
        }

Also I changed MarkerOptions pinImage and pinIconImage from type Image? to Int so I should put one of images from drawable. Maybe thats the issue?
That's how MarkerOptions look now:
data class MarkerOptions(
    val coordinate: GeoPoint,
    val pinImage: Int,
    val pinIconImage:  Int,
    val shieldImage: Image? = null,
    val tag: String? = null,
    val label: Label? = null,
    val balloonText: String = ""

)

And thats how it looked:
data class MarkerOptions(
    val coordinate: GeoPoint,
    val pinImage: Image,
    val pinIconImage: Image? = null,
    val shieldImage: Image? = null,
    val tag: String? = null,
    val label: Label? = null,
    val balloonText: String = ""
    
)


I wasn`t able to input Image type in MarkerOptions, that's why I changed types
